# Checked out clearcase file but can't check in

Tags: eclipse, clearcase, rad

Using RAD 8.5/ClearCase 7.x, I checked out many files. I made my changes and was able to check many of the files back in (using the GUI RAD interface). However I'm unable to check in many other files by right-clicking on them in Eclipse. When I do right-click on them, the check-in & out options are disabled but the 'Add to source control' is enabled - RAD/CC react like these files are not in source control, but they've been controlled for many years. I am able to do a 'Find checkouts' (using RAD) and it lists those files. If I start up CC Explorer and check those files in my view, they show as 'View-private file'.

I've tried deleting one of these files via CC Explorer and then try to "re-add" it via the RAD GUI but I still get a generic error at that point that doesn't tell me anything.

How do I at a minimum get these files back in a state that I can check them out?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error adding '(full file path of file within view)' to source control.

Comment: I've done a lot of searching on the rmview command w/ the option uuid. That discussion appears to always be in the context of an inaccessible or otherwise unavailable view. That's not the case here. The view is accessible, is currently being used but is probably corrupted and needs cleaning. Will using the rmview with the uuid option, after cleaning the checkout & derived object references, leave the view in the vob? If it does remove the view from the vob, how do I simply uncheck out files using cleartool (on a Windows machine)?

Answer (score 1):

After working w/ our inhouse CC support staff, we've gone the route of them going in and undoing the check outs of the remaining files and then creating a new view. Then delete the "bad" view from my RAD workspace (as well as from the VOB) and import the new view. Because of additional CC plugin issues, we're also uninstalling RAD, WAS, and Clearcase to reinstall them. So this current situation is now closed.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in clear case view, this may not be the proper answer as I am not doing through eclipse, but it may help others. Solution was 
Go to version tree of the file, right click on the checked-out node and there check in option was enabled.